# Handling IGetResponse on Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using the [Get API](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/get.html) of Nest, but I don't know how to typecast the respone (IGetResponse) to the specific type of the document, something like this:

```
var response = client.Get<MyDocument>(documentId);
return response.Document(); // Or something like this that returns a MyDocument type
```

Also, is there a way to get the document for another unique field or only the Id is accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.Source` holds document of type `MyDocument`.

[As documentation says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html), you can use get api to get documents only by their ids.

You can tell elasticsearch to treat other field from document as Id.
With NEST you can do this as follows:

```
var indicesOperationResponse = client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
    .Index(indexName)
    .AddMapping<Document>(m => m.IdField(f => f.Path("uniqueValue"))));

client.Index(new Document{UniqueValue = "value1"});

var getResponse = client.Get<Document>(g => g.Id("value1"));
```

My document class:

```
public class Document
{
    public string UniqueValue { get; set; }
}
```